# Query to get one to many and many to one employee project relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

Table:

```
create table emp_project_mapping 
(
    emp_id varchar(10),
    pro_id varchar(10)
)
```

Records:

```
insert into emp_project_mapping values('E101','P1'),
                                      ('E101','P2'),
                                      ('E102','P1'),
                                      ('E103','P3'),
                                      ('E104','P3'),
                                      ('E105','P4');
```

**Query 1**: Find the employee who is working on more than one project.

Expected Result:

```
emp_id  pro_id
--------------
E101    P1
E101    P2
```

**Query 2**: Find the more than one employees working on the same project.

```
emp_id  pro_id
--------------
E103    P3
E104    P3  
E101    P1
E102    P1
```

**Try**:

Query 1:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  emp_id,
            pro_id,
            DENSE_RANK() over(order by emp_id) empid_rank,
            DENSE_RANK() over(order by pro_id) proid_rank
    FROM emp_project_mapping
)
SELECT emp_id,pro_id
FROM CTE
WHERE empid_rank = 1 and proid_rank>1
```

Output:

```
emp_id  pro_id
---------------
E101    P2
```

Query 2:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  emp_id,
            pro_id,
            DENSE_RANK() over(order by emp_id) empid_rank,
            DENSE_RANK() over(order by pro_id) proid_rank
    FROM emp_project_mapping
)
SELECT emp_id,pro_id
FROM CTE
WHERE empid_rank > 1 and proid_rank = 1
```

Output:

```
emp_id  pro_id
----------------
E102    P1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this....

For first solution

```
        ;WITH CTE
        AS
        (
            SELECT  emp_id,
                    pro_id,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY pro_id) empid_rank
            FROM emp_project_mapping
        )
        SELECT * from emp_project_mapping WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT emp_id
        FROM CTE
        WHERE empid_rank > 1 )
```

For second solution

```
        ;WITH CTE
        AS
        (
            SELECT  emp_id,
                    pro_id,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pro_id ORDER BY emp_id) proid_rank
            FROM emp_project_mapping
        )
        SELECT * FROM emp_project_mapping WHERE pro_id IN (SELECT pro_id 
        FROM CTE 
        WHERE proid_rank>1)
```

Comment: For identifying employee who is working on more than one project current solution might not work. As with dense rank you will get rank #1 for only one employee, for example E105 if he works for project P3 as well then your solution might not work....                                                   Instead you can use group by project with having clause count(distinct emp)>1

Comment: @Mahesh: thanks for your suggestion, i have updated my query please check now.